# Good .Net Remoting Tutorial/Guide

Tags: .net, remoting

Does anyone have any links to a good, concise, Tutorial or guide to .Net remoting? Would be grateful!

Thanks (sorry for the short post!)

Edit: I am now aware of: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/remotingsimpleeng.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing beats Ingo Rammer's book on .NET Remoting from Apress
[http://www.amazon.com/Advanced-NET-Remoting-Ingo-Rammer/dp/1590590252](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590590252)

Comment: Yup, I learned .net remoting from this book as well.

Comment: Excellent, the bible for remoting...

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have some specific requirements that require .NET Remoting you should probably take a look at [Windows Comminication Foundation (WCF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) instead. WCF provides the functionality of .NET remoting (and more) and as far as I know WCF is now the recommended technology to use.

Comment: Unless he has a corporate requirement not to use anything new.  A lot of places aren't using WCF yet because they have myopic IT rules, etc.

Comment: Yeah, Developing in .Net 2.0 otherwise I would use WCF

Answer (score 0):

Here are my bookmarks on .NET Remoting articles: http://delicious.com/dreikanter/remoting. the most detailed manual is "Remoting Architecture in .NET". Other ones contains different usage examples of this technology.